# In Meteor, is it possible to set the type of a sub-schema dynamically using the values of its siblings as arguments? ( Collection2 )

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-collection2

## Background

I am in the process of designing some blogging software for someone who has very little experience with the internet. Observing their interaction with the internet, the client grows more annoyed as the number of forms they must fill out increases. To remedy this, I would like to keep the creation of the blog on one page with all editing done inline.

The way they build a blog post is to

1. Select a 'block' of content, which places it on the canvas.
2. Edit the block inline until they are satisfied with the material,
3. Add another block, rinse and repeat until finished.
4. Save the post, which then sends the data from the session to the server.

I have already created the packages that allow all the inline content creation to work without a hitch. However, getting the schema to play ball is another beast in general. I would like to structure each block as a Spacebars template, and have a template field in each post specify which template to render. Where this approach breaks down is that I do not want one massive schema for all possible posts. It would be nice to extend the subschema of a Post to match the Template field instead of whittle a massive post down to a small one. Unfortunately, Collection2 is proving to be a bit finicky allowing me to extend sub-schemas dynamically based on the template field.

---

### The Basic Schema

```
@Posts = new Mongo.Collection 'posts'

Schemas = {}
Blocks  = {}

#  B L O C K S  -------------------------------------------------------------

Blocks.Title = new SimpleSchema
  title:
    type: String
    defaultValue: 'Click me to enter a title for this post!'
    max: 200

Blocks.Body = new SimpleSchema
  body:
    type: String
    defaultValue: 'Click me to enter some body text!'
    label: 'Body'

blockMap = {
  'Title': Blocks.Title
  'Body': Blocks.Body
} 


#  S C H E M A S  -----------------------------------------------------------

#- START PROBLEM AREA ---

Schemas.Block = new SimpleSchema [
  # Used by Spacebars to render dynamic templates. 
  template:
    type: String
    label: 'The name of the template into which this block is rendered.'
    allowedValues: ->
      return _.keys(Blocks)   # Only allow blocks that exist to be set as templates.  
  data:   # Uses the template field to elect which data it provides to it. 
    type: blockMap[@field('template').value]
  ]
#- END PROBLEM AREA ---

Schemas.Post = new SimpleSchema [ Schemas.Base,
  blocks:
    type: [Schemas.Block]
    minCount: 2
  ]

@Posts.attachSchema(Schemas.Post)
```

---

### Fixture Data:

```
Posts.insert
  blocks: [
    {
      template: 'Title'
      data:
        title: 'Hello World!'

    },
    {
      template: 'Body'
      data:
        body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
               Labore dolorum, et nemo eius libero incidunt saepe est alias,
               harum nesciunt ducimus facilis reiciendis. Sit odit,
               laudantium. Provident laudantium, enim adipisci.'
    }
  ]
```

---

### Experimentation

In the section I've highlighted above, as it is written above, the `data: { type: ... }` Object does not have a field method. Only the autoValue method seems to have access to it, which is odd. This doesn't work either.

```
data:
  type: eval('Blocks.' + @field('template').value)
# >> TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'field'
```

So how do I get access to the field?

The type property can be passed a constructor function, so it will evaluate properties just fine. It just cannot seem to receive the data from the template property.

---

### Where to go from here

Unfortunately, this does not allow for the dynamic schema construction that I am looking for. So my question is this. If I can pass a constructor to the type property of the data field, is there in any way possible that I can somehow pass the value of the template field as well so that I may dynamically render templates as I go? I would like to continue using Collection2, as it is awfully convenient. Another approach I am toying with is making one giant Block schema and then selecting parts of it with Collection2 for each block type.

Any advice? (Refactoring, passing code, etc.)

Comment: This leaves me really confused. 1 post has 1 title & 1 body. Could you explain how this works compared to a standard blog?

Comment: Basically, each set of content is a block, and you can build up a blog post by stringing a bunch of building blocks together. Once you put one down on the page, you can edit the content in place, which then updates the database on submit. 

The example I posted is a basic one. It may be hard to visualize from reading, but it's similar to Qards. [Here's a video showing how that works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xx1SdYHC-SA)

Comment: Gotcha... so 1 post has many blocks. Each block has many fields?
Make a separate schema for each block type.
Then for the post schema, include 1 (or an array, up to you) of each of the block schemas. Add the `optional` flag (or `minCount: 0`, if you allow arrays)

Comment: Alright I'll try that out. I may have been over complicating this whole idea. It's been a long day :)

Comment: no worries, extra set of eyes always helps! As a rule of thumb, whenever I use `eval` for anything except user-inputted javascript, I take a nice long walk because I'm probably headed down the wrong path. Post your solution when you've got it worked out, it's an interesting idea.

Comment: I can get around the eval(...) issue by simply making a hash map of my template names, such as `var blockMap = { 'Title' : Block.Title }`. The main issue is that I cannot get access to the fields method from the autoValue function. Doing some investigation, I've found that the autoValue function is passed the MongoDocument as an argument, so if I can somehow get a hold of that instead of of using `this`, I may be able to replicate the functionality. Will keep you posted.